# vmware vcenter 5.1 installation with FQDN error

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vcenter

I'm trying to install vCenter 5.1 on a windows 2012 dedicated (with SQL express standalone)
During the installation of the Single Sign On module i've a warning
"the fully qualified domain name cannot be resolved with nslookup. if you continue the installation some features might not work correctly. for detailed requiments see the installation and setup guide"

The only indication that i've found are about the reverse zone dns resolution.. and this works!

- i've verified that the dns works properly with nslookup

> ```
> C:\Users\admin>nslookup srv6.mydomain.local
> Server:  srv2.mydomain.local
> Address:  172.25.4.22
> Nome:    srv6.mydomain.local
> Address:  172.25.1.26
>
>
> C:\Users\admin>nslookup 172.25.1.26
> Server:  srv2.mydomain.local
> Address:  172.25.4.22
>
> Nome:    srv6.mydomain.local
> Address:  172.25.1.26
> ```

(all ip are right: I've the vCenter=srv6 and DC+DNS=srv2 on different vlan)

- i've tryed to force the resolution of the ip changing the [..]\drivers\etc\hosts file
- i've disabled the IPv6 support
- i've used all combination with domain prefixes (explicit, by dhcp, undefined..)
- i've disabled all antivirus/firewall (kaspersky end point 10)

is this a bug of vcenter 5.1.0-1065152 ?
have you got any suggestions for me?

Comment: What do you have as primary dns suffix? Find it with `ipconfig /all | find /i "dns suffix"`

Comment: the dns suffix now is "mydomain.local" (i've done various tests)

Comment: I don't really trust `nslookup` and it's poorly documented NetBT fallback catches. Try to verify the reverse lookup, either by using `dnscmd`/`dnsmgmt` or try this in PowerShell: `([System.Net.DNS]::GetHostByAddress([System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse("172.25.1.26"))).HostName`

Comment: `PS C:\Users\admin> ([System.Net.DNS]::GetHostByAddress([System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse("172.25.1.26"))).HostName

SRV6.mydomain.local`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error doing the same (fresh install of 5.1 on windows 2012).
My DNS setup is also perfectly okay (incl. reverse lookup), so I just ignored the warning.

Everything installed fine and is now working without any issues.

Answer (score 2):

*(you don't need to obfuscate your private IP addresses... it hurts question readability)*

Please make sure you have the reverse zone configured properly and records populated for that IP/name. VMware SSO is odd in that it *can* query the forward and reverse on *every* interface on the server. Do you have multiple interfaces on this system? It sounds like a physical server, so possibly?

Check the log details in:
`{system drive}\users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\vm_ssoreg.log`

Comment: the system is a virtual machine with only one interface, the DNS is populated with forward and reverse data.. now i'm going to read the log

Comment: i've found only 2 vm*.log files in that dir: vminst.log and vm-sso-javalib.log. In the first one at the last rows i've copied
ResolveIPwithNSLOOKUP::Executed nslookup successfully:0
VMware Single Sign On-build-1064107: 09/14/13 16:34:57 contents of file - Server:  srv2.mydomain.local
Address:  172.25.4.22

Nome:    srv6.mydomain.local
Address:  172.25.1.26

.
VMware Single Sign On-build-1064107: 09/14/13 16:34:57 Not able to find -

Comment: but "nslookup 172.25.1.26" in cmd works!

Answer (score 0):

If you added reverse dns record after first check, try to flush dns cache

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

and try again